# rss parsing DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm trying to get all categories and push them into my `array`, so far I'm doing it this way:

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load('myxml.xml');
  $arr = array();
  foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $items = array ( 
      'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->nodeValue
      );
    $arr [] = $items ;
  }
```

This works if we have only 1 cat, however, my `xml` has several categories per item. What would be a good way of doing this?

```
<item>
  <title>Submit</title>
  <category>Foo</category>
  <category>Bar</category>
</item>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('myxml.xml');
$arr = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => array()
    );

    foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('category') as $catNode)
    {
        $item['date'][] = $catNode->nodeValue;
    }

    $arr[] = $item;
}
```

- Christian

Answer (score 0):

You need nested loops:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('myxml.xml');
$arr = array();

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $itemNode) {
    $items = array( 
        'title' => $itemNode->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date'  => array()
    );

    foreach ($itemNode->getElementsByTagName('category') as $categoryNode) {
        $items['date'][] = $categoryNode->nodeValue;
    }

    $arr[] = $items;
}
```

Comment: But would that be part of arr[]? I'm trying to push them into my arr[]